# How do I limit a character appearance in a regex?

Tags: regex

I am stuck with a problem that challenges me to create the regular expression for binary numbers (containing `0`s and `1`s). But the string should only match if the binary number only contains a maximum of five `1`s. **How do I limit a character appearance in a regex?**

Examples:

- `01101101` is correct
- `01111100` is correct
- `10110011` is correct
- `01111110` is wrong
- `11111110` is wrong

Comment: You missed the part about wrong examples

Comment: Thanks, this was my solution to the issue, `^0*1?0*1?0*1?0*1?0*1?0*$`, https://regex101.com/r/XinvHD/1, but I prefer @bunji answer.

Comment: What language are you processing this in?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
^0*(?:10*){,5}$
```

Essentially this matches any combination of `'1'`s and `'0'`s but only allows a substring containing a single `'1'` character to occur five times at most.

Try it out here:
https://regex101.com/r/JKV1Uk/2

**Explanation:**

- `^` matches the beginning of the string
- `0*` matches zero or more `'0'`s
- `(?:10*){,5}` matches up to 5 `'1'`s followed by any number of zeros
- `$` matches the end of the string

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, `^0*(10*){0,5}$` also works. So I want to ask what are the functions of `?` and `:` there?

Comment: The `?:` makes a group [non-capturing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do). From your description it didn't seem like you needed to capture any groups so I made it non-capturing out of habit since there is a [slight cost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41444807/why-is-regex-search-slower-with-capturing-groups-in-python) to using capturing groups with most regex engines. You are right though, it works either way.

Answer (score 0):

If you engine supports [lookaheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), and there can not be more than 8 times a 1 or 0 and the 1 should not occur more than 5 times, you might use:

[`^(?=[01]{8}$)(?!(?:0*1){6,})[01]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/qzY2Ez/1)

**Explanation**

- `^` Begin of the string
- `(?=` Positive lookahead that asserts that what is on the right side

  - `[01]{8}$` Match 8 times a 0 or 1 until the end of the string
- `)` Close lookahead
- `(?!` Negative lookahead that asserts that what is on the right side

  - `(?:0*1){6,}` The pattern zero or more times a 0 followed by a 1 `0*1` is not repeated 6 or more times (so 0 till 5 times is valid)
- `)` Close negative lookahead
- `[01]+$` Match 0 or 1 one or more times
- `$` The end of the string